# Como ressignificar bytes sem undefined behavior?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, conversão-de-tipo

#### Detalhes

Em assembly, C, C++, C# com unsafe e outras linguagens é possível reinterpretar código binário no endereço como de tipo diferente do original. Tipo converter `int*` para `float*` em C, quer dizer que se aponta para inteiro valendo `0x3F800000` então também tem lá floating point `1.0f`.

Apesar de permitir algoritmos que requeiram controle refinado dos bits e mesmo que se espere algo óbvio de uma releitura, ainda assim é considerado U.B. (undefined behavior), ou seja, comportamento indefinido, não se sabe o que compilador/interpretador vai fazer com aquilo.

Se não me engano, quase sempre converter ponteiros é considerado U.B. e quero saber o motivo. Por que fazer isso dá B.O.? Por exemplo, ler float de inteiro afinal não dá um resultado esperado devido à formatação conhecida que o float tem? O que pode sair diferente?

Aqui o Visual Studio otimiza tão bem que o disassembly até encontra constantes após as conversões dos valores conhecidos. Que eu saiba, no máximo o compilador pode

- usar código qualquer entre vários possíveis que representem o valor (como float NaN, que tem vários códigos binários que o representam, aí o compilador escolhe qualquer um) e
- não conservar a ordem de leitura e escrita ao otimizar código em situações mais complicadas (tipo em arrays percorrendo índices ao invés de trabalhar com simples variáveis).

Fora isso, não sei e por isso eu não entendo.

*Inclusive para mim no compilador se evitaria o segundo U.B. de maneira óbvia: sendo ele implementado para manter a ordem de instruções de leitura e escrita do que não garante acesso a bytes em endereços distintos. Em outras palavras, se o que o programador espera é aquela ordem então só muda se houver certeza absoluta de que o resultado será o mesmo. Ainda assim, acho que esse problema já aconteceu comigo programando em VC++. Para que isso?*

#### Perguntas

Então a primeira pergunta é **por que ressignificar valores na memória é U.B. tão generalizadamente?** Agora a segunda pergunta é **como em caso de necessidade de fazer isso garantimos que não seja U.B. e o resultado seja certamente o mesmo?** E claro, preferencialmente sem desativar otimizações.

Para ficar mais claro, se eu quero em C++ duas funções que convertam ponteiros (uma para "read and write" e outra para "read only") de maneira genérica com template, tipo assim...

```
template< typename DstDataType , typename SrcDataType >
inline DstDataType* RemeanPtrAs( SrcDataType *srcPtr ){
    return (DstDataType*)srcPtr ;
}

template< typename DstDataType , typename SrcDataType >
inline const DstDataType* RemeanPtrAs( const SrcDataType *srcPtr ){
    return (const DstDataType*)srcPtr ;
}
```

Por que é U.B. e como faço exatamente essas funções com procedimentos não U.B. e que façam exatamente o mesmo que se espera delas?

**Edit: Esse código é U.B.? Não sendo por si só, possibilita ao otimizar a chamada inline? Será que essa é a solução? Trocar typecasts por `memcpy` e `memmove` sempre evita U.B.?**

```
# include <string.h>

template< typename DstDataType , typename SrcDataType >
inline DstDataType* RemeanPtrAs( SrcDataType *srcPtr ){
    DstDataType* dstPtr ;
    memmove( &dstPtr , &srcPtr , sizeof(void*) ) ;
    return dstPtr ;
}

template< typename DstDataType , typename SrcDataType >
inline const DstDataType* RemeanPtrAs( const SrcDataType *srcPtr ){
    const DstDataType* dstPtr ;
    memmove( &dstPtr , &srcPtr , sizeof(const void*) ) ;
    return dstPtr ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A questão que vc exemplificou através do código em:

```cpp
template< typename DstDataType , typename SrcDataType >
inline DstDataType* RemeanPtrAs( SrcDataType *srcPtr ){
    return (DstDataType*)srcPtr ;
}

template< typename DstDataType , typename SrcDataType >
inline const DstDataType* RemeanPtrAs( const SrcDataType *srcPtr ){
    return (const DstDataType*)srcPtr ;
}
```

Pode ser substituída pelo uso de interfaces que fazem a conversão de variável não-constante para variável somente leitura nos pontos de acesso, e também pela expressão [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast):

```cpp
int i = 3;                              //variável inicial não-constante
const int* i_cptr = &i;                 //ponteiro constante
int* i_ptr = const_cast<int*>(i_cptr);  //casting de ponteiro constante para ponteiro não-constante
*i_ptr = 4;                             //mudança de valor da variável não-constante
std::cout << *i_ptr; //4
```

Remover ou atribuir o status de const/volatile em runtime é trivial, mas esteja ciente de que modificar o valor de variáveis constantes, mesmo depois de utilizar const_cast, ainda é UB. Nada pode mudar isso. Const_cast é útil para acessar interfaces, mas transfere a responsabilidade de manter a constância de valores constantes para você, o programador.

> por que ressignificar valores na memória é U.B. tão generalizadamente?

O ecossistema em C++ não é bem assim, além de diversos tipos diferentes de [ponteiros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), existem outros recursos que permitem acesso direto à memória. Desde [std::memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), e [move semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) até [variáveis atômicas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), onde vc pode selecionar a [ordem de acesso da memória](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) durante o multi-threading e otimizar rotinas a nível de instrução única no processador.

> como em caso de necessidade de fazer isso garantimos que não seja U.B. e o resultado seja certamente o mesmo?

A única maneira de garantir o comportamento correto de qualquer programa é através do estudo aprofundado do ambiente de desenvolvimento. No seu caso, é necessário buscar maior entendimento das regras do C++ e entender as ferramentas disponíveis. Programar em C++ é bastante diferente de programar em C e essas diferenças sempre existem por um motivo. Por exemplo, quando você se refere à falta de [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union) com unions em C++, ela acontece devido à maneira como C++ lida com [alinhamento de memória e aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object). Para se manter consistente com essas regras, é necessário que unions só tenham um tipo de cada vez, sem manter dois tipos ao mesmo tempo.

Outros recursos ou situações são deliberadamente determinadas como UB no Padrão da língua. Tanto para que implementações de compiladores (ou da STL) sejam mais eficientes, quanto para que outros recursos mais complexos se façam disponíveis.

> Por que é U.B. e como faço exatamente essas funções com procedimentos não U.B. e que façam exatamente o mesmo que se espera delas?

```cpp
template <typename T>
T* to_non_const(const T* src) {
    return const_cast<T*>(src);
}

template <typename T>
const T* to_const(T* src) {
    return src;
}
```

Note que essa implementação pode ser perigosa para usuários desavisados, uma vez que escondendo o uso de const_cast, pode ser entendido que as responsabilidades atreladas a seu uso não são mais necessárias. Ambas funções são redundantes, pois não fazem nada além de mascarar o uso de const_cast.

Comment: Aviana, perceba que a primeira função que fiz converte `SrcDataType*` (ponteiro "read and write" para "source data type") para `DstDataType*` (ponteiro "read and write" para "destiny data type"), ou seja, não aplica restrição de escrita, apenas aplica a nova interpretação dos dados.

Comment: Da mesma maneira, perceba que a segunda converte `const SrcDataType*` (ponteiro "read only" para "source data type") para `const DstDataType*` (ponteiro "read only" para "destiny data type"), ou seja, não tira restrição de escrita, apenas aplica a nova interpretação dos dados.

Comment: E o tempo todo abordei o ressignificado dos dados quanto ao formato do tipo de dado e sem a mudança no que diz respeito à presença ou ausência de `const`. Quer dizer, me esforcei pra deixar claro que quero manter `const` como está e mudar o tipo do ponteiro.

Comment: Pimeiramente, perdão pelo erro, estava cansado e durante a minha leitura não tinha enxergado por esse ângulo. O cerne da minha resposta não muda muito. Casting de tipos usando a notação de C `int var = (int) foo;` não é a maneira recomendada em C++. O jeito certo é através de `static_cast<T>` e `dynamic_cast<T>`. Exemplo:

`template <typename IN, typename OUT>
OUT to_out(IN var) { return static_cast<OUT>(var); }`

Comment: Não existe necessidade de algo mais complicado que isso. Um tipo T em um template mantém as propriedades const/volatile automaticamente, não é necessário definir funções diferentes para cada combinação possível. Como disse anteriormente, a não ser que exista um motivo ou comportamento especial que deve ser executado antes do casting, esse tipo de função é redundante. Você pode simplesmente usar `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` ou `reinterpret_cast` diretamente. Se a conversão não for possível, `static_cast` não deixa seu programa compilar e `dynamic_cast` retorna `nullptr`.

Comment: Quer dizer que nenhum desses `_cast` de C++ provocam ub?

Comment: `const_cast` e `reinterpret_cast` são os mais perigosos e vc deve usar com cuidado, mas `static_cast` e `dynamic_cast` te dão sinais claros quando algo está errado.

Comment: Hm, sei. Gostaria de saber as "regras de ub" a cerca disso, especialmente `reinterpret_cast` que é aparentemente o que se usa nesse contexto.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast